# How to start and break down an assignment

Tags: java

I have recently started with java programming in school and we just received a task. I´m struggling to figure out how to start grasping the problems so figured I could ask you guys for help on how to break it down.

I will try to explain as good as I can ( it´s originally written in norwegian).

**Task:**

The recommendations from the EU on the distribution of grades in a large number of candidates is to be allocated characters as follows:

(A. 10%)
(B. 25%) 
(C. 30%) 
(D. 25%) 
(E. 10%)

Note that this distribution is for those who have passed and that it should apply to a large number of students.

We will create a program that does the following:

The program will create a table of points achieved for 20 students (this is admittedly a small number of students, but it will be sufficient in this task). 
The points to be generated in random range from 0 to 200 points. All that achieves 30 points or more has passed.

It should print a list of points for all students (student number is the index in the table).
Calculate the points for each of the students who have passed in percent.
Furthermore, we assign students a grade based on the above recommendation. It will print a
list of grades for all students. Those who have failed to have the grade F.

Finally, we want to know how many people have gotten A and how many have gotten B etc. This is printed
in an orderly manner.
Try to let the different tasks in this exercise be solved by separate objects so that main ()
method pretty much starts it all.

**Edit:**

I should probably said more about what we have been introduced to in lectures. From what I can recall we have seen the **for** and **while** loop, **do-while**, **if-else**, **switch**, **random**, **array** and **array2D.**

I have been experimenting now and this is what I have so far. On the right path?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Random random = new Random();

    int[] students = new int[20];
for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
  students[i] = random.nextInt(200);

for (int i:students)
    if ( i >= 30 ) {
        System.out.println(i + "\tpassed");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(i + "\tfailed");
    }
}
```

Next on the list is probably to replace the "if-else" with a "switch" statement and introduce the grades.

All thoughts is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you write something to show how much you can do. I. assume you can write and run a "Hello World" program.  Then when you have a specific problem you can ask a specific question and get a specific answer.  For such a general question I suggest you use object orientated principles and write more code.

Comment: Please check out this excellent set of recommendations from Professor Patricia Shanahan: [So, You Need to Write a Program but Don't Know How to Start](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html). She is not infrequently seen answering questions on this site, you can easily tell from her posts that she has taught many and that she has true concern for helping others learn Java.

Comment: Thank you, will absolutely read this several times

Answer (score 2):

Generally the best way to approach these problems in school is to take a look at what sort of lessons have been taught during the build up to the assignment and try to incorporate as much of that into your assignment.

Also it's great to look at these things one paragraph at a time. Usually in school they are very good about being explicit on what you need to do.

For example let's look at the first paragraph you wrote: There are 3 sentences and 3 instructions. 
(i)   Create a table of 20 or more students
(ii)  Assign a random value between 0 and 200
(iii) All that have achieved 30 more have passed.

Look at these three and then look at your lecture notes. Did you learn a way to store a lot of points of data? Maybe an Array? If so you'll probably need an Array.

Did you learn how to do random numbers? Then you'll need that for step 2.

Did you learn how to do a method to check a condition and do something? (IF structure?) You need that for number 3.

I'd just just start coding and see if you can actually fullfill the instructions. In the beginning don't worry about OO principles. Get comfortable with syntax and breaking down the problem. Also **get done early** ask your teacher to look at your code and ask them to explain why certain ways are better than others.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time, will go over the steps you listed for sure.